# Cryptic text / weird characters on selected websites opened in Firefox

Tags: firefox, web

Since about a week, some (not all) web pages opened in Firefox (86.0.1 (64-bit)) look like they have some kind of encoding error, see following screenshot. I already created a new profile a few days ago and thereafter it worked fine again. But now it seems the error is back again. I can see the same issue in private mode and also after disabling all extensions.

Note that only selected web sites have this phenomenon and opening them in another browser (e.g., Safari) works perfectly fine, so I'm pretty confident that it has to do with some setting in Firefox. Interestingly, when looking into the page's source everything looks fine.

I already tried the suggestion to change the config option `network.http.accept-encoding.secure` in `about:config` to `gzip, deflate` but that didn't help. Any ideas how to solve this permanently?

[image: example website]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by some fonts on my system. After trying out disabling the option "Allow pages to choose their own font [...]" in the Firefox settings everything looked fine. So I just restored the default macOS fonts and voilá - the issue is finally solved.